# Arduino PWM LED blinking on four pins, each pin's intensity and time period based on the previous pin

Tags: arduino-uno, led, arduino-nano, pwm

I am trying to make four LEDs glow using my Arduino, based on some relationship between them in terms of brightness and the time for which LEDs glow.

For example, the relationships are:

```
pin_3_value = 250  // LED 1 intensity
pin_5_value = 1.2 * pin_3_value // LED 2 intensity
pin_7_value = 1.1 * pin_5_value  // LED 3 intensity
pin_13_value = 0.59 * pin_7_value  // LED 4 intensity

time_till_led_1_on = 100
time_till_led_2_on = time_till_led_1_on * 1.2
time_till_led_3_on = time_till_led_2_on * 2.4
time_till_led_4_on = time_till_led_3_on * 1.2
```

I understand that only a fixed set of values are permitted as input to the `analogWrite()`. Is there some way to implement this relationship on the Arduino? I cannot use a `digitalWrite()`, as the output of PWM pins are used for something else; making the LED glow is just for testing purposes.

The code I have written so far:

```
// Brightness level for the four pins

int Brightness_1 = 255;
int Brightness_2 =  Brightness_1 * 2;
int Brightness_3 = Brightness_2 * 3;
int Brightness_4 = Brightness_3 * 4;

// Delay or time between  LED turn off and next LED turn ON

int Delay_1 = 500;
int Delay_2 =  Delay_1 * 1.1;
int Delay_3 = Delay_2 * 1.2;
int Delay_4 = Delay_3 * 1.3;

int pins[] = { 2, 4, 5, 7 }; // An array of pin numbers

void setup()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) // The array elements are numbered from 0  to num pins - 1
        pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT); // Set each pin as an output
}

void loop()
{
    // Loop through each pin...
    analogWrite(pins[0], Brightness_1 ); // Turning it on,
    delay(Delay_1);                      // pausing,
    analogWrite(pins[0], 0);             // and turning it off.

    analogWrite(pins[1], Brightness_2); // Turning it on,
    delay(Delay_2);                     // pausing,
    analogWrite(pins[1], 0);            // and turning it off.

    analogWrite(pins[2], Brightness_3); // Turning it on,
    delay(Delay_3);                     // pausing,
    analogWrite(pins[2], 0);            // and turning it off.

    analogWrite(pins[3], Brightness_4); // Turning it on,
    delay(Delay_4);                     // pausing,
    analogWrite(pins[3], 0);            // and turning it off.
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I see this is an old question, and before going into it, I was going to see how you went with coming to a solution. There are several things about this. 1) you're setting the values to a fixed previous value, you'll need to use functions or at the least pointers to retrieve each value dynamically, and 2) ditch the delays unless you're after a fixed rate each loop (again each one is indefinitely a fixed value). Also some indication of what you're expecting it to look like would help. Is it a Knight Rider forward and backward swipe you're after, or one direction only?